# Inline if (?:) doesn't work in _delay_us()

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc, atmega

When I'm trying to use `_delay_us(condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false)` in my 1-Wire implementation, delay doesn't work and i get no answer from my device, but it works fine when i replace it with:

```
if(condition) _delay_us(value_if_true);
else _delay_us(value_if_false);
```

When i displaying inline if value on lcd it shows the correct value.

So what's the difference between this two notations?
How can i make inline if work in _delay_us() ?

Comment: What is `_delay_us`? Is it a macro? I'd try `_delay_us((condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false))`

Comment: I'd concentrate on value_if_true/false and i'd rather put `_delay_us((condition) ? (value_if_true) : (value_if_false))` that'll save you any trouble !

Comment: I'm guessing that _delay_us() is a compiler intrinsic. These things typically require a numeric literal as the compiler will recognise it and convert it directly the correct number of instructions required to give you the delay. So it must usually be a numeric literal value, or some other constant that the compiler knows the value of.

Comment: If it were a compiler problem, the compiler would warn/error on it. b3niup said the delay does not work so i guess here the problem is at runtime

Comment: Here You have described _delay_us: [link](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html).

condition is just a volatile variable, true and false values are #define'd and substituted by precompiler

Neither jpalecek nor Eregrith suggestions doesn't help

Comment: run avr-gcc -S on your source file, it'll output the assembly which will contain clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) clearly says:

> In order for these functions to work as intended, compiler optimizations must be enabled, and **the delay time must be an expression that is a known constant at compile-time.** If these requirements are not met, the resulting delay will be much longer (and basically unpredictable), and applications that otherwise do not use floating-point calculations will experience severe code bloat by the floating-point library routines linked into the application.

Answer (score 0):

Oops ... utterly offbase thoughts, but leaving them here to remind me to think before posting.

you need:     condition ? _delay_us(value_if_true) : _delay_us(value_if_false)

basically the same syntax as the if statement

think

(condition)?(evaluate if condition was true):(evaluate if condition was false)

Comment: No, the original syntax is perfectly fine here.

Comment: Not sure that's correct as an argument to a function. Never used it that way. I've always considered ternary operator as an equivalent to the "if" syntax.

Comment: given the difference in function observed, I wonder what the objdump would show. If it is written that way, and functioning as stated, I wonder if it was optimized out.

Comment: I guess that's what happens on a weekend, now that I'm thinking. I have used them before as arguments to functions, to my chagrin, I guess sometimes you get used to using something but forget you do it.

Comment: This actually works, because now `_delay_us` has a compile-time constant as its argument (which it has to be for it to work).